# Can someone explain me the Risch algorithm for solving integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

I have been studying integration for quite a while now, and as swiftly as I went through differential calculus, I got struck in integration when I learnt that there are as such no "rules of integration" as we have got in differentiation. There are indeed some standard methods known like the method of substitution, by parts, by partial fraction decomposition, etc. however, there exists no rule to determine which method we should use when and how. I always had to go over a function and using trial-and-error use various methods until I could find a suitable procedure. However, I discovered that online calculators like [www.integral-calculator.com](http://www.integral-calculator.com) quickly and easily solves all integrals showing all the steps. I often wondered how they did, until one day I read below the calculator, that it uses something called as Risch algorithm, which in fact all such integral calculators use, to solve the problems. I now, badly want to know what is the algorithm, and using that how can we find out the integral of a function.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: If you are asking out of curiosity then see @GEdgar's answer. But if you are looking for a method to help you solve integrals in practice like those you are likely to encounter on an exam then it is an impractical approach and you are better to stick to specific tricks that you were taught for dealing with each form. In the wikipedia page for the Risch algorithm it says: "The complete description of the algorithm takes over 100 pages". See the examples there to get a feeling for why this might be an impractical algorithm unless you're a CAS (and sometimes even if you're a CAS - see in wiki).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm

Comment: The WP article just talks about the algorithm, it doesn't show us what is the algorithm and how to use it.

Comment: @Justlookingforthemoment Did you not read Snaw's comment?

Answer (score 5):

An introduction ...

*Rosenlicht, Maxwell*, [**Integration in finite terms**](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/2318066), Am. Math. Mon. 79, 963-972 (1972). [ZBL0249.12106](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0249.12106).

The complete algorithm takes a big book to describe... Bronstein's book describes "half" of the algorithm.  Unfortunately, he never did part II.

*Bronstein, Manuel*, Symbolic integration. I: Transcendental functions, Algorithms and Computation in Mathematics. 1. Berlin: Springer. xiii, 299 pp. (1997). [ZBL0880.12005](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0880.12005).

Comment: There is only 1 page in the link that you have shared. What about the remaining pages?